# gfortran line length limit

Tags: line-breaks, gfortran, intel-fortran

Is there a way of disabling the line length limit in the gfortran compiler? I am porting from ifort to gfortran and I wonder if there is an easy way to do so without going through the code and introduce line continuation by hand everywhere where it is needed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Investigate the options

```
-ffixed-line-length
-ffree-line-length
```

GCC manual:

> `-ffixed-line-length-n`
>
> Set column after which characters are ignored in typical fixed-form lines in the source file... Popular values for n include 72 (the standard and the default), 80 (card image), and 132 (corresponding to “extended-source” options in some popular compilers). n may also be ‘none’, meaning that the entire line is meaningful and that continued character constants never have implicit spaces appended to them to fill out the line. `-ffixed-line-length-0` means the same thing as `-ffixed-line-length-none`.
>
> `-ffree-line-length-n`
>
> Set column after which characters are ignored in typical free-form lines in the source file. The default value is 132. n may be ‘none’,
> meaning that the entire line is meaningful. `-ffree-line-length-0`
> means the same thing as `-ffree-line-length-none`.

Comment: Could you please help me find which standard these (and, why not, all other) options have been introduced since? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I apologize, but I simply haven't found it. I can find all options on gcc.gnu.org, still I couldn't find a table with a "introduced in" column. Can you at least tell me if I'm searching for an existing thing? Again, apologize.

Comment: FYI if you have intel fortran compiler, [the compiler flag is `-extend-source` which gets you 132 max line length](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options/compiler-option-details/language-options/extend-source.html). i do not know if there is a 'switch like `-ffree-line-length`.

Answer (score 3):

I used `-ffree-line-length-none` so that my extra long lines in the source code didn't cause errors